# How do I multiply two columns and then reuse that value without doing the forumla over and over

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am trying to multiply two columns and then use that value to do a CASE statement, I'm not really sure how to ask this or if it's even possible so please bare with me.

```
        SELECT (table1.price)*(table2.quantity) AS "total price", CASE WHEN (table1.price)*(table2.quantity) < 10 THEN 3 CASE WHEN (table1.price)*(table2.quantity) > 10 THEN (CASE WHEN (table1.price)*(table2.quantity) < 20 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END
        FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.itemid 
        WHERE table1.id = 41212;
```

Is there a way to make the table1.price*table2.quantity a function of could I make it an alias and reuse that Alias? I have to later use it in the WHERE statement too.

Comment: Use a CTE or sub query.

Answer (score 0):

Try a subquery:

```
SELECT tmp."total price", CASE WHEN tmp."total price" < 10 THEN 3 CASE WHEN tmp."total price" > 10 THEN (CASE WHEN tmp."total price" < 20 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END
FROM
(
    SELECT (table1.price)*(table2.quantity) AS "total price"
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.itemid 
    WHERE table1.id = 41212;
) AS tmp
```

Comment: I see, I did not know this was possible, many thanks.